# How can I get more helpful GLSL compilation errors?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsles

I'm trying to learn OpenGL ES on Android, but one thing is making this rather frustrating and difficult. I can't get any usable error messages from the GLSL compiler. And learning GLSL when you don't get *any* useful feedback except "it compiles" and "it does not compile" is rather difficult.

I found that `glGetProgramInfoLog` is supposed to contain the errors from the compiler, but the only thing I can get out of this is something like

> Link failed because of invalid fragment shader.

Am I using the correct command to get the compiler errors, or is there a different one I should use? Is it even possible to get more meaningful error messages from the GLSL compiler?

I'm using OpenGL ES 3.0 on Android 4.3 and a Nexus 10 as target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[glGetShaderInfoLog](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) gives you shader-level debug output.